# AspectJ doesn't weave an interface when the aspect is outside the interface

Tags: java, aspectj

When I implement interface via inner static aspect Impl

```
public interface EventSpaceSupplement {
    String getEventSpace();
    EventSpaceSupplement setEventSpace(String name);
            ...
    static aspect Impl {
        private String EventSpaceSupplement.eventSpace;
        public String EventSpaceSupplement.getEventSpace() {
             return this.eventSpace;
        }
        public EventSpaceSupplement setEventSpace(String EventSpaceName) {
             this.baseSetEventSpace(EventSpaceName);
             return this;
        }
        public EventSpaceSupplement baseSetEventSpace(String EventSpaceName) 
        {
            this.eventSpace = EventSpaceName;
            this.eventManager = EventManager.getEventListenerForMe(this.getEventSpace(), this);
            return this;
         }        ...
    }

}
```

it works fine. All files are woven properly.
But it doesn't work I'm trying to separate aspect and interface into two files:

```
public aspect EventSpaceSupplimentA {
    private String EventSpaceSupplement.eventSpace;
    public String EventSpaceSupplement.getEventSpace() {
        return this.eventSpace;
     }
    public EventSpaceSupplement setEventSpace(String EventSpaceName) {
        this.baseSetEventSpace(EventSpaceName);
    return this;
    }
    public EventSpaceSupplement baseSetEventSpace(String EventSpaceName) {
       this.eventSpace = EventSpaceName;
       this.eventManager = EventManager.getEventListenerForMe(this.getEventSpace(), this);
        return this;
}
    ...
}
```

and

```
public interface EventSpaceSupplement {
    String getEventSpace();
    EventSpaceSupplement setEventSpace(String name);
}
```

The class doesn't woven:

```
public class TestClass extends Timplements EventSpaceSupplement {
    @Override
    public EventSpaceSupplement setEventSpace(String eventSpaceName) {
        this.baseSetEventSpace(eventSpaceName);
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Idea looks fine in both cases, it navigates through ctl+left click. But class are not woven and the are ajc complation error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved magical tambourine.
I was adding java default implementation stubs. For example:

```
public interface EventSpaceSupplement {
    default String getEventSpace(){return null;}
}
```

Rebuild. EventSpaceSupplimentA caused compilaion override error. But **then** I remove default implementation  back.

The code is absolutely the same. But after that manipulation aspects are inexplicably began be woven.